Sveltekit serving custom /media directory
I've set a MEDIA_ROOT variable in the .env file to a seperate folder in the file system (oustide the sveltekit app) I wanted to serve as-is for user uploads like images and such, vite just gave me an error and to fix all I needed is to update vite.config.ts and add this:
...
server: {
    fs: {
        allow: [
            `${env.MEDIA_ROOT}`
        ]
    }
}

Been working fine on dev, once I build the app and run npm preview I get not found errors on anything that references /media
SvelteKitError: Not found: /media/posts/36/c87dec0a-9584-40d9-b6d1-490f9f6d0eae.png
    at resolve2 (file:///D:/Projetos/Svelte/site/build/server/index.js:4118:18)
    at resolve (file:///D:/Projetos/Svelte/site/build/server/index.js:3950:34)
    at Object.handle (file:///D:/Projetos/Svelte/site/build/server/chunks/hooks.server-CfL5HxaF.js:32:16)
    at async respond (file:///D:/Projetos/Svelte/site/build/server/index.js:3948:22)
    at async Array.ssr (file:///D:/Projetos/Svelte/site/build/handler.js:1261:3) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}

I'm not sure if I simply can't serve any directory outsite the app, or if I'm missing any configuration.
My svelte.config.js doesn't have anything meaningful by the way, just the base generated by the app.
I was hoping to serve files/store user files on a directory outisde the app that might be on a different disk entirely.
